# Execute a function for specific amout of time - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout

I would like to animate a input slider when the user arrived at this div.
To watch if the user scrolled to this div I am using a directive, which triggered the change of value of my slider. Here is the code :

```
directive("scroll", function ($window, $timeout, $interval) {
          return function(scope, element, attrs) {
              angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                   if (this.pageYOffset >= 1500) {
                     var timeout = $timeout(function(){
                          var interval = $interval(function(){
                            scope.slider += 4;
                          },25);
                      }, 0);
              });
          };
      })
```

This work well, increasing the value smoothly, with a nice animation effect however this doesn't stop increasing. I tried to add :

```
                      var second_timeout = $timeout(function(){
                        scope.slider= 400;
                      }, 100)
```

To fix a value, but it "jumped" and then continues to increase.

I also tried to add a while loop to avoid the slider's value to be higher than 500, this worked but there's no more "Animation" effect.

I chose this way of doing it, which may appear complicated because I didn't find any way to make it with CSS animations.

Does a pure angularJs function exist to specify an amount of time during which a function  should be executed?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining an interval. That function will continue running and that is why it does not stop.

You could do something like this:

```
var timesRun = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    timesRun += 1;
    if(timesRun === 60){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    scope.slider += 4; 
}, 25);
```

Comment: Ok, this is what creates the smooth effect of the animation I guess.. I don't know any other way to create it. Isn't it possible to stop an interval after like two seconds?

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. What is the difference between setInterval and interval? Do they work the same way?

Comment: $interval is an angularjs wrapper for the javascrict setInterval function. In your case using $interval is OK.

Comment: Actually if I replace setInterval by $interval, it doesn't stop.

Comment: But are you canceling it with $interval.cancel? $interval cancels with $interval.cancel. setInterval cancels with clearInterval

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. If I want this directive to trigger only once (to avoid the slider moving each time I scroll after), what is the best way to do it? I am currently trying with a global variable initialized to 0, increased when doing through this directive, and I test his value before entering the interval function, but actually it doesn't care about that..

Comment: Oh no, it is working fine actually :) Thank you for your help!